# compiler c code, optimise for low power

Tags: compiler-construction, energy

I want to make an embedded ‘C’ code compile that has the option to execute a program with the minimum amount of power, conventional compilers optimise for speed or size.  This will mean that the compiler will optimise down the number of logic toggles on both the address and data lines because each toggle charge-pumps energy.

Comment: Good for you, and what is your question?

Comment: A compiler can only do so much with the code it's given - you can probably achieve a lot more power reduction by optimising your code - the less unnecessary computation and I/O you do the less power you use.

Comment: For a starting point, if i had a program to count from 32 down to 0, and i want to reduce the energy required; Program 2 below spreads the power dissipation around the microprocessor because the least significant bit is not being thrashed!. I could probably up my CPU clock speed from 5Ghz to 50Ghz as well because there is no LSB thrashing! Program 1 For (x=32;x!=0;x--); Program 2 – Same thing. x=0x80000000; do { x=x>>1;} while (x) –  gary 33 mins ago

Comment: As a starting point,
I need a simulation model of the microcontroller silicon – internal track capacitances and leakage currents – also a full debugging emulator with trace memory.
I put the trace file into the simulation model and the theoretical amount of power to run the program is calculated in Joules.  I can then tweak my program code to get rid of obvious waste.

Comment: a simple example, of reading ahead initialize vars:
before c code source:
a=0xaaaaaaaa;
b=0x55555555;
c=0xaaaaaaaa;

after optimize, lines of code have been moved around:
a=0xaaaaaaaa;
c=0xaaaaaaaa;
b=0x55555555;

Comment: within the cpu core there are some 128 bit base-1 registers and a instruction set to use them, they are much faster and use much less power than base-2 registers. but can only count from 0 - 128

Answer (score 0):

Good luck on that goal (of developing your own C compiler optimizing for energy; you should get a PhD doing that). You could perhaps try using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for that purpose.

See also the [MAGEEC](http://mageec.org/) project; but I guess you should not expect to find any time soon a compiler magically and automatically optimizing for low-power. It should be a whole program optimization. (you might want some assisted, semi-automatic, optimization).

And in many hardware devices, most of the power is consumed by something else that the CPU. For instance, in smartphones, it is the screen and the communications which eat the most energy (so you should optimize these). In fact, you probably should lower the frequency (in some application specific fashion).

Answer (score 0):

It's a laudable goal and practical depending upon how recent your hardware is. I don't think you can do much for older hardware. I also don't think optimizing logic toggles (to minimize leakage current?) is going to get you much unless your program is very very simple and very very small. Have you done any experiments validating that you can get significant gains?

If you are using more modern hardware, in terms of processor and peripherals, you can create a compiler that can optimize for power. Modern processors and peripherals have energy conservation states. You can rewrite code to take advantage of these states and get a noticeable reduction in energy usage. In addition, you have to consider your environment. The processor is a major energy hog, though mobile processors targeting the embedded market, such as cell phones, have made big strides in reducing the processor's energy usage during idle times.

I'm delivering a presentation on the topic of how to write your software apps for energy efficiency. I can't pass it to you because it isn't published yet. I hope to be writing a series of blogs on the same topic over the next few months. I've done other writings on software and energy efficiency if you want to look me up at the Intel software website. As a caveat, most of my energy related work has been on Intel GP and HPC processors. The principles still apply to Intel mobile processors and other modern processor architectures aimed at the mobile and low power embedded markets.